# AngularJS : having problems with $scope,factory returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im learning AngularJs.
And I find my self enjoying it, But im stuck with this code

my controller

```
$scope.getQuestionaires = function(){
var formdata = $scope.formdata;
var items = parseInt(formdata.items);
var num_letter = parseInt(formdata.num_letter);
var num_missing_letter = parseInt(formdata.num_missing_letter);

var send_data = {
    api_type: 'select',
    tb_name: 'tb_spelling',
    tb_fields: false,
    tb_where: false,
    tb_others: "LIMIT "+items
};

return factory.getRecords(send_data);
}
```

my factory

```
factory.getRecords = function(data) {
  return $http.post('models/model.php', {
     params: data
    }).then(function(response) {
    records = response.data;
    return records;
  });
};
```

Situation : When I `console.log($scope.getQuestionaires)`, It returns

> function (b,j){var
>   g=e(),i=function(d){try{g.resolve((b||c)(d))}catch(e){a(e),g.reject(e)}},o=function(b){try{g.resolve((j||
>   d)(b))}catch(c){a(c),g.reject(c)}};f?f.push([i,o]):h.then(i,o);return
>   g.promise} controllers.js:307 function (a){function b(a,c){var
>   d=e();c?d.resolve(a):d.reject(a);return d.promise}function d(e,f){var
>   j=null;try{j=(a||c)()}catch(g){return b(g,!1)}return
>   j&&j.then?j.then(function(){return b(e,f)},function(a){return
>   b(a,!1)}):b(e,f)}return this.then(function(a){return
>   d(a,!0)},function(a){return d(a,!1)})} controllers.js:307
>
> [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Question : My problem is that i only want the array of objects, how can i do that? I think theres a lot i got to improve about my code...I need help :)

Thx

====================================
Fixed

Thx to Chandermani's answer,

Got it!

My controller

```
$scope.createTest = function(){

        $scope.getQuestionaires();

    }

    /*question getter*/
    $scope.getQuestionaires = function(id,question){

        /*send_data here*/

        var records = factory.getRecords(send_data);

        records.then(function(response){
           $scope.questionaires = response.data;
        });


    }
```

My factory

```
factory.getRecords = function(data) {
      return $http.post('models/model.php', {
         params: data
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getQuestionaires returns response for your $http post method which is a promise and not the actual data, since the call is async.

Change the method `getRecords` to

```
factory.getRecords = function(data) {
  return $http.post('models/model.php', {
     params: data
    });
};
```

When you call the method `getQuestionaires` do something like

```
$scope.getQuestionaires().then(function(response){
   //access response.data here
});
```

Try to understand the async nature of such request. If you ever call async methods within your own functions you can access the response by either returning the promise or provide a callback as a argument to the function.